# Performance difference of code in aspx and cs files for showing and hiding a control dynamically

Tags: asp.net, performance

I was thinking about the performance when I use code to hide some control in aspx page using delimiters or in cs file.

For e.g. 
If I have a panel and I want it to get shown following some condition, so I can achieve this by two ways

1: Using code in aspx file, something like this

```
<% if(isAllowed) { %>

<asp:Panel ...></asp:Panel>

<% } %>
```

2: In the code file, something like this

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlMyPanel" Visible="false"></asp:Panel>
```

And in cs file

```
if(isAllowed)
  pnlMyPanel.Visible=true;
```

In my view, first way should be good as it will not at all create any Panel in the page.
Am I correct here?

Please guide me which method is preferable

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I have no idea which is quicker, but I doubt that the difference will have any appreciable effect on the performance of your application.

Answer (score 0):

If by performance you mean the size of final HTML generated by page, in both cases no HTML code would be rendered hence no impact on page weight. For maintainability I would recommend putting it in cs, that ways its easier for the *next person* to follow the logic flow.

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago, I became obsessed with creating forms that only loaded exactly what they needed, e.g. using `Page.LoadControl()` to load subcontrols. By and by, I became aware that the headaches created by this in terms of event lifecycle and reference availability were not insurmountable, but onerous enough that I was spending much more time than I wanted dealing with it.

So I stopped doing that. And it was good.

I learned a valuable lesson: **Don't worry about performance problems unless you have one.**

Computing power is cheap, and most websites in most situations won't ever come close to a performance problem. So write code that is easy to understand and maintain first, then worry about optimizing when (more likely, if) performance ever becomes a problem.

So to answer your question, whichever is faster, do this in cs:

```
pnlMyPanel.Visible = isAllowed;
```

By the way there is an important distinction between this and using an "if.." construct to set it visible only when your condition is true.

Because ViewSate is enabled by default, if you set the panel to visible, it will remain visible on subsequent postbacks, regardless of whether the `isAllowed` condition becomes false. So I would recommend being in the habit of always assigning visibility to form elements that are conditionally visible. This also means you never need to worry about setting the Visible and EnableViewState properties in markup.